# Not able to detect nearby AltBeacons

Tags: android, bluetooth, altbeacon

I'm trying to use a Bluetooth beacon library for Android made by Radius Networks (http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/index.html) to detect nearby beacons (also made by Radius). However, when I run the app I've created, it doesn't detect anything.

The library detects AltBeacons by default, and I've configured the beacons to advertise using the AltBeacon format. I started the advertise rate at 1Hz, but increased it to 5Hz and then 10Hz to see if that would help, but it made no difference. The transmit power should translate roughly to 5 meters, and I've been doing my testing within one meter. And the configuration app made by Radius detects the beacons without any issues.

Here is my manifest file, which includes the permissions the library doc tells you to include (it also says to include a location permission, but it says that versions 2.6+ of the library include it - I'm using v. 2.12.4):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.whawk.beaconsensor">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And here is the activity class, which should report detected beacons once per second:

```
package com.example.whawk.beaconsensor;

import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.altbeacon.beacon.Beacon;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconConsumer;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.RangeNotifier;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.Region;

import java.util.Collection;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BeaconConsumer {

    private BeaconManager beaconManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        beaconManager.bind(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        beaconManager.unbind(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> collection, Region region) {
                Log.i("MainActivity", "Beacons: " + collection.size());
                //TODO Update the value text views with the appropriate RSSI values
                for (Beacon beacon : collection) {
                    String name = beacon.getBluetoothName();
                    String id1 = beacon.getId1().toString();
                    int rssi = beacon.getRssi();
                    Log.i("MainActivity", "Beacon: [name: " + name + ", ID1: " + id1 +
                        ", RSSI: " + rssi + "]");
                }
            }
        });

        try {
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("com.example.whawk.region",
                    null, null, null));
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

When I debug the app on my phone, the only log message I see is the one reporting how many beacons were detected, which is always zero ("Beacons: 0"). I don't see any errors or any other messages in the log that would indicate anything is misconfigured.

Also, I've been doing my testing on a Samsung Galaxy S7 running Android 7.0.

I'm new to Android development and working with Bluetooth beacons, so it's likely I missed something simple. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the Location permission was not granted, and I needed to add some code to prompt the user for that permission since that's required starting in Marshmallow. Once I used the code provided by the doc to make the request (http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/requesting_permission.html), which I didn't think I needed at first, it worked!